# Solve Google Captchas automatically

Tags: python, captcha

So basically I have done a reader through Google demo where it grabs the CAPTCHA site-key, then it takes us to `main` method where I run multiprocessing where I enter how many processors I want to run at the same time and then it goes to `Checker` where there is new thread for every `AntiCappy` (that solves CAPTCHA) and then goes to `Printer` to basically print out the easy stuff. And that's pretty much it. Nothing hard really.

However, I found as soon as I start 1 task it takes my CPU from 2% load to 25~%. Isn't that way too much for just 1 printer?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests, names, _thread, json, os, sys, time, random, webbrowser, multiprocessing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from colorama import init, Fore, Back
from datetime import datetime
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, Proxy, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask


URL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo'

api_key = ''



tokens = []

def grabCaptcha():

    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(URL)
    captchafinder = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    Key_Found = captchafinder.find('div', {'class': 'g-recaptcha'})['data-sitekey']
    log(Fore.GREEN + 'Sitekey received: ' + Fore.RESET + Key_Found)
    print("----------------------")
    main(Key_Found)
    
def sendToken():
    while not tokens:
        pass
    token = tokens.pop(0)
    return token['token']
    
def antiCappy(Key_Found):
    apikey = api_key
    site_key = Key_Found  # grab from site
    url = URL

    client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
    task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
    job = client.createTask(task)
    job.join()
    captcha = job.get_solution_response()

def Printer(prod, captcha, Key_Found):

  fname = names.get_first_name(gender='male')
  lname = names.get_last_name()


   print(fname)
   print(lname)
   print(Key_Found)
   print(captcha)

    

def text():
    text = """

   Hello code review!

      """

    print(text)
 

def Checker(thread, Key_Found):
    global prod
    prod = int(thread) + 1
    _thread.start_new_thread(antiCappy, (Key_Found,))
    token = sendKey()
    Printer(prod, token, Key_Found)


def main(Key_Found):

    while True:
        try:
            accounts_num = int(input(Fore.WHITE + 'How many printers do you wanna run? [NUMBERS] \n' + Fore.RESET))
        except ValueError:
            print(Fore.RED + "Stop being stupid" + Fore.RESET)
            continue
        else:
            jobs = []

            for i in range(0, accounts_num):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Checker, args=(str(i), Key_Found))
                jobs.append(p)
                time.sleep(.5)
                p.start()

            for p in jobs:
                p.join()

            sys.exit()


def log(msg):
    currenttime = Fore.YELLOW + str(time.strftime("[%H:%M:%S]")) + Fore.RESET
    sys.stdout.write("%s %s\n" % (currenttime, str(msg)))
    sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    text()
    grabCaptcha()
```

[image]

I guess this shouldn't take that much usage for just 10?

#### Update:

Below is what I have edited so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests, names, _thread, json, os, sys, time, random, webbrowser, multiprocessing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from colorama import init, Fore, Back
from datetime import datetime
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, Proxy, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask


URL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo'

api_key = ''

tokens = []

def grabCaptcha():

    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(URL)
    captchafinder = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    Key_Found = captchafinder.find('div', {'class': 'g-recaptcha'})['data-sitekey']
    log(Fore.GREEN + 'Sitekey received: ' + Fore.RESET + Key_Found)
    print("----------------------")
    main(Key_Found)

    
def captureToken(token):
    expiry = datetime.now().timestamp() + 115
    tokenDict = {
        'expiry': expiry,
        'token': token
    }
    tokens.append(tokenDict)
    return

    
def sendToken():
    while not tokens:
        pass
    token = tokens.pop(0)
    return token['token']

def antiCappy(Key_Found):
    apikey = api_key
    site_key = Key_Found  # grab from site
    url = URL

    client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
    task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
    job = client.createTask(task)
    job.join()
    captcha = job.get_solution_response()

def Printer(prod, captcha, Key_Found):

  fname = names.get_first_name(gender='male')
  lname = names.get_last_name()


   print(fname)
   print(lname)
   print(Key_Found)
   print(captcha)



def text():
    text = """

   Hello code review!

      """

    print(text)


def Checker(thread, Key_Found):
    global prod
    prod = int(thread) + 1
    _thread.start_new_thread(antiCappy, (Key_Found,))
    log('Profile-{} starting thread...'.format(prod))
    token = sendToken()
    Printer(prod, token, Key_Found)


def main(Key_Found):

    while True:
        try:
            accounts_num = int(input(Fore.WHITE + 'How many printers do you wanna run? [NUMBERS] \n' + Fore.RESET))
        except ValueError:
            print(Fore.RED + "Stop being stupid" + Fore.RESET)
            continue
        else:
            jobs = []

            for i in range(0, accounts_num):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Checker, args=(str(i), Key_Found))
                jobs.append(p)
                time.sleep(.5)
                p.start()

            for p in jobs:
                p.join()

            sys.exit()


def log(msg):
    currenttime = Fore.YELLOW + str(time.strftime("[%H:%M:%S]")) + Fore.RESET
    sys.stdout.write("%s %s\n" % (currenttime, str(msg)))
    sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    text()
    grabCaptcha()
```

**Maybe an idea for the issue:**

*I have tried a lot now to try see the issue and I think I finally found it. I have now updated my code to now see what I have done. It was stupid of me to now provide the fully information but it should be good now. BUT I know now the issue. So the issue is sitting on _thread.start_new_thread for sure. Because the problem that is now if I remove the _thread and just have the method antiCappy(). This will just wait until the method is done which is pretty logic. However if I want to run it concurrently then I need to use some sorts of thread which cause some CPU usage which why gives me a high CPU. So maybe I need to now find a way to actually make it run concurrently while it doesn't take alot of usage of CPU.*

Comment: Any reason as to why you're using `_thread` instead of `threading`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Not really but I found that when I didnt have etc a _thread. It would not continue the code which means I needed manually to close the thread to make it continue the code...

Comment: ^ Adding more information : Because if im not using _thread and call `antiCappy()` method, Then it will wait until it has solved it until it runs the other one which is not concurrently like I want, Whenever I added _thread then it starts to run concurrently but eating the CPU!

Comment: Where does the "Profile-X Solving captcha..." prints that we can see in the screenshot come from? It is not in your code, nor is the `sendKey` function… And what to say about this `sendToken` function that is never being used, the obvious indentation error in `Printer` and half its parameters not being used… Is this your real code as it appears in your editor?

Comment: Hello @MathiasEttinger, I have tried a lot now to try see the issue and I think I finally found it. I have now updated my code to now see what I have done. It was stupid of me to now provide the fully information but it should be good now.

***BUT*** I know now the issue. So the issue is sitting on ```_thread.start_new_thread``` for sure. Because the problem that is now if I remove the _thread and just have the method antiCappy(). This will just wait until the method is done which is pretty logic. However if I want to run it concurrently then I need to use some sorts of thread which cause

Comment: some CPU usage which why gives me a high CPU. So maybe I need to now find a way to actually make it run concurrently while it doesn't take alot of usage of CPU.

Comment: The problem is, I dont know if this is turning into a problem which maybe should be at Stackoverflow or if it fits to code review.

Comment: You're already using `multiprocessing` to run your searches in parallel, so there is no need of threads here. Calling `antiCappy` directly in `Checker`  is the right move. But you need to provide clean and runnable code before we consider the question on topic.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @MathiasEttinger but the issue gonna be that calling antiCappy without any thread will make the script to wait for the method, When the method is done then the next task gonna start. What I want it to do is that it should run concurrently so without needing to wait for a task to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Some preliminary style guide pointers:

- Keep `import`s of different packages in separate lines. Ordering them such that the packages which python provides are listed first, and the ones installed over `pip` are imported later.
- `webbrowser`, `json`, `random` are imported, but never used.
- Global constants should be named in `ALL_CAPS` format.
- Function names should follow the `snake_case` pattern. And should be consistent with the rest of your program scheme. You are mixing them all up: `main`, `Printer`, `grabCaptcha`, `text` etc.
- Instead of having variables named like `s` or `r`, name them properly; for eg. `session`, `response`.
- Add docstrings to your functions so that another developer is able to understand what the function does.

---

You are creating a subprocess and passing it an integer converted to string, which is converted back to integer inside the function.

```
args=(str(i), Key_Found)
```

Just pass the argument `i`?

---

`time.strftime` already returns a string. No need to wrap it inside another `str` again.

---

Your indentation is a bit off in the `Printer` function. That might be just a copy-pasting error.

---

You should also wrap the program inside a `try-except` block against the following exception:

```
python_anticaptcha.exceptions.AnticatpchaException
```

---

I ran the program on my linux machine, and the CPU usage was not affected as much as you claimed. It might be a Windows specific issue? Or the IDE you're using.

Comment: I will answer few of them!

To the `args=(str(i), Key_Found)` - the 'i' is for the for loop to make it run the exact input you enter. I took it from Multiprocessing website itself.

About the CPU. Its very strange. I tried running with Pycharm AND CMD and I got a high usage. But how come you dont get any? :O

Comment: @WeInThis I mean just pass args as: `args=(i, Key_Found)`

Comment: Ohhh okey! I didn't thought about it! Will check the others soon.Really appreciate the help aswell!